# vba : why click event is diffused on initialising?

Tags: vba, excel

In excel, I have an userForm with checkBox dynamically created from a list 
on initialize, I call a sub to affect a click event to my checkbox.
I have then a classmodule call MyEvents in wich I declare click event for check box.
Here is the class module MyEvents :

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents chkGroup As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub chkGroup_Click()
    Debug.Print "chkGroup_Click -----> " & chkGroup.Caption
End Sub
```

Here is the sub on userForm :

```
Private Sub initCheckBox(chanelList As Variant)

    Dim myEvent As MyEvents
    Dim chkBox As Collection
    Dim n As Long, j As Integer, i As Integer
    n = Application.CountA(chanelList)
    Dim checkBoxChanel() As MSForms.CheckBox
    ReDim checkBoxChanel(n) As MSForms.CheckBox
    n = 1
    j = 1
    i = 1
    Set chkBox = New Collection
    chkBoxNum = 0
    For Each chanel In chanelList
        Set myEvent = New MyEvents
        Set checkBoxChanel(n) = Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "chkBoxChanel" & n)
        Set myEvent.chkGroup = Frame1.Controls("chkBoxChanel" & n)
        chkBox.Add myEvent
        With checkBoxChanel(n)
            .Top = j
            .Left = i
            .Caption = chanel
            .AutoSize = True
            .Value = True
            .Enabled = False
        End With
        n = n + 1
        i = i + 80
        If n Mod 3 = 0 Then
            j = j + 20
            i = 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Can someone explain me why `clickevent` is diffused on initialising. Is it the normal behavior ?

Comment: You should indent code 4 spaces to get syntax highlighting, and not use `<code>` tags. Also, what do you mean by "diffused"?

Comment: hi, thanks for your interest. I mean chkGroup_Click is called when userForm is initialising, even if user doesn't click on check box.

Comment: Do you have any code in 'UserForm_Initialize' that could directly or indirectly trigger your event? If not, then you would need to set a switch first thing in UserForm_Initialize and turn off at exit, then check switch in your clickevent.

Comment: Declare myEvent at the module level, i.e., before any code. Right now it's going out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I've found the trick. Setting check box value to true is like clicking on check box ! to avoid this, I just have to affect event after setting value to true. Thanks to all for you comment and answers